# sharepoint online numeric textfield

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have this code with Sharepoint online using React.  It works fine if the value is a string.  What do I do for numeric values?

````
    ```
               <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-u-sm4 block">
              <label className="ms-Label">WindowsID</label>
           </div>
           <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-u-sm8 block">
              <TextField value={this.state.windowsID} onChanged={this.handleWindowsID}/>
           </div>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're using ['office-ui-fabric TextField](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/textfield), the value is string Type so you need convert numeric to string.

```
<TextField name="txtA" value={this.state.windowsID.toString()}
```

Or try below package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-string-operations

Comment: Suppose I want to do calculations.

Comment: Create a function to calcuation <TextField name="txtA" value={this.Calculate(this.state.windowsID)} , Calculate is custom function